# PHP won't parse on Apache2 - CentOS 7

Tags: php, linux, apache, configuration, centos7

I am trying for days to enable php on my server. The web server is up, but php is not parsed.

1. First things first: the server is a CentOS 7 running apache2 and php 7.
   Everythign seems to be correctly installed:

   OS: `uname -a`

   ```
   Linux rafiki 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 16 17:03:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   ```

   and :`cat /etc/redhat-release`

   ```
   CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
   ```

   apache: `httpd -v`

   ```
   Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
   Server built:   Jul 18 2016 15:30:14
   ```

   PHP: `php -v`

   ```
   PHP 7.0.10 (cli) (built: Aug 20 2016 07:47:25) ( NTS )
   Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
   Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
       with Zend OPcache v7.0.10, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
   ```
2. Then, in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` there is this line:

   ```
   Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
   ```

   And in `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/`:

   ```
   10-php.conf  00-base.conf  00-dav.conf  00-lua.conf  00-mpm.conf  00-proxy.conf  00-systemd.conf  01-cgi.conf
   ```

   `10-php.conf` content:

   ```
   <IfModule prefork.c>
       LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule !prefork.c>
      LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7-zts.so
   </IfModule>
   ```
3. Here is output for `ls /etc/httpd/modules/ | grep php`

   ```
   libphp7.so
   libphp7-zts.so
   ```
4. In /var/www/, there is a test.php file, which content is:

   ```
   <?php phpinfo(); ?>
   ```

   When I try http://[myserver.domain]/test.php, apache serves the raw file, without parsing php code.

I went through a lot of researches including StackOverflow, but none of the results had a solution working for me.

**Can someone please help me to get php run properly? Is there something I am doing wrong ?**

**Solution:**

As pointed out by @kyshel, a simple reboot worked.

Comment: I met your condition once, but after i reboot the server, it works well. You can have a try.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked. However, I still don't know why. Do you know why restarting services didn't get the job done ?

Comment: I do not know. Maybe apache was not load php module, or the cache or something cause this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rebooting the server (as others have already suggested). It worked for me.